# Update table using alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fill some fields in a table getting informations from other records of the same table.
I tried to write a query to explain what I want to do:

```
update globale2
set
  nita = t.nita,
  tita = t.tita,
  notaita = t.notaita
where
  neng = t.neng and
  nita is null
  (select nita, neng, tita, notaita from globale where uris='mma' and nita is not null) as t
```

edit to eplain better:

every records have these fields: "nita", "tita", "notaita", "neng" ("neng" cannot be null)

I want to fill these fields: "nita", "tita", "notaita" (where "nita" is empty)
with the same values from another record where "neng" equals the other "neng"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can however, join the two tables.

```
UPDATE  globale2 g
        INNER JOIN globale gg
            ON g.neng = gg.neng
SET     g.nita = gg.nita,
        g.tita = gg.tita,
        g.notaita = gg.notaita
WHERE   g.nita IS NULL
        AND gg.uris = 'mma' 
        AND gg.nita IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

assume there is a table A_temp, with two columns 'one' and 'two'.
TABLE A_temp

```
ONE    TWO
1       2
```

this is the present status of the table.

The query

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM A_temp ) A SET one = A.two where one = '1'
```

updates the table as

```
ONE    TWO
2      2
```

Hope you get the idea and that it helps..